# Jquery: Get all elements of a class that are not decendents of an element with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem**: Given a specific container dom element (the window, a div, a fieldset, etc), find all elements of a class (.FormWidget) inside that DOM element, searching recursively through all of that container's descendants. Include, **but do not look inside**, elements with the matching class (.FormWidget). The elements can be nested to *n* levels.

For example, given this HTML:

```
<fieldset id="MyFieldset" class="FormWidget FieldSetMultiplier">
  <legend>My Legend</legend>

  <div>
    <label for="Field1">Field1</label>
    <input type="text" name="Field1" value="" id="Field1" class="BasicInput FormWidget">
  </div>

  <div id="SomeWidget" class="FormWidget">
    <label for="Field2">Field2</label>
    <div name="Field2" id="Field2" class="FormWidget RestrictedComboBox"></div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<div>
    <label for="Field3">Field3</label>
    <input type="text" name="Field3" value="" id="Field3" class="BasicInput FormWidget">
</div>
```

**Example 1:**

Let the pseudo Jquery function ".findButNotInside()" represent the functionality I'm looking for.

```
$(document).findButNotInside('.FormWidget');
```

Should return only #MyFieldset and #Field3. Starting from the window, field 1 and 2 and #SomeWidget are FormWidgets, but they can't be included since the function is not allowed to look inside other .FormWidgets to find FormWidgets. Anything inside the .FormWidget fieldset is off limits.

**Example 2:**

```
$('#MyFieldset').findButNotInside('.FormWidget');
```

Should return only `#Field1` and `#SomeWidget`. It should be looking for `.FormWidget`s that are inside the targeted fieldset, `#MyFieldset`, but should not return #Field2 because it is not allowed to look inside of a .FormWidget (in this case #SomeWidget) to find other .FormWidgets.

I'm thinking this can be done with the right function and selector, but I'm not sure of how that selector should be constructed?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a copy & paste homework assignment

Comment: Use filter() or create a plugin

Comment: @MikeRobinson Hard to say now that the Homework tag has been deprecated. ;)

Comment: You're missing a closing div tag for `#Field2`

Comment: @MikeRobinson: It's not homework, just a problem I wasn't sure if Jquery had an answer for. @ shmiddty: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.fn.findButNotInside = function(selector) {
    var origElement = $(this);
    return origElement.find(selector).filter(function() {
        var nearestMatch = $(this).parent().closest(selector);
        return nearestMatch.length == 0 || origElement.find(nearestMatch).length == 0;
    });
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyLq7/).  The trick is to check that the `nearestMatch` is actually within our search context.

And note that this invalid:

```
$('window').findButNotInside('.FormWidget');
```

...because there is no `<window>` tag.  What you want is:

```
$(document).findButNotInside('.FormWidget');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("container-selector").find(".class").not(".class .class");
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution relies on known information about the HTML structure:

```
$('body .FormWidget').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('.FormWidget').length == 0;
}).css("border", "solid 3px red");​

$('#MyFieldset .FormWidget').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('.FormWidget').length == 1;
}).css("border", "solid 3px blue");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwgZu/

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't think of a more elegent "jqueryish" solution.  But, this can be done recursively.

http://jsfiddle.net/zzBMq/

```
function findIt($elements){

    $elements.children().each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.is(".FormWidget")){
            // do something with the matched element
            $this.css("border","1px solid red");
        }else{
            // make the recursive call
            findIt($this);
        }
    });
}

findIt($("#MyFieldset"));
```

You could obviously turn this into a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.findButNotInside = function(selector){
        var _n,_o,elemArr=[];
        this.find('.FormWidget').each(function(){
            _o = _n;
            _n = $(this);
            try{
                if(_o&&_o.find(_n).length){
                    _n = _o;
                    if(elemArr.indexOf(_o)==-1) throw _o;
                }else throw _n;
            }catch(e){
                elemArr.push(e);
            }
        });
       return $().add(elemArr);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guerilla/p9fMX/