# jquery selecting children not nested in a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have some problems with a jQuery selector.

Let's say I have the following html where `(...)` stands for an undefined number of html tags.

```
(...)
<div class="container">
  (...)
    <div class="subContainer">
      (...)
        <div class="container">
          (...)
            <div class="subContainer"/>
          (...)
        </div>
       (...)
     </div>
   (...)
</div>
(...)
```

Let say that I have a javascript variable called `container` that points to the first div (with class container).
I want a jquery that selects the first subcontainer but not the nested one.
If I use`$(".subContainer", container);` I'll get both of them.

I've tried using

```
$(".subContainer:not(.container .subContainer)", container);
```

but this returns an empty set.
Any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: `$(".subContainer:first", container)` `$(".subContainer", container).first()` might work.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624058/jquery-get-all-elements-of-a-class-that-are-not-decendents-of-an-element-with-t/12625354#12625354

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate. This question wants a child element, avoiding nested ones. The other question wants a sibling/nephew element, avoiding any child elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Jquery: Get all elements of a class that are not decendents of an element with the same class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624058/jquery-get-all-elements-of-a-class-that-are-not-decendents-of-an-element-with-t/12625354#12625354) I've developed the following solution.
Thanks to all.

```
$.fn.findButNotNested = function(selector, notInSelector) {
    var origElement = $(this);
    return origElement.find(selector).filter(function() {
        return origElement[0] == $(this).closest(notInSelector)[0];
    });
};
```

Comment: Excellent solution. I suggest renaming the method to `$.fn.findButNotNested`, since that's what this does (the other answer was for not inside). (I tried to edit, but it was rejected.)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `direct child` selector:

```
$("> .subContainer", container);
```

If `container` is a jQuery object that refers to top-level `.container` element you can also use `children` method:

```
container.children('.subContainer');
```

Or `find` and `first` methods:

```
container.find('.subContainer').first();
```

Comment: This does not work because the .subContainer is not a direct child. (...) may contain many divs.

Comment: None of these work in all the cases. What if the first child of the main .subContainer is a div with .subContainer that has a child div with .container?

Comment: There is a solution to the problem at the end of this page (accepted awnser)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first subContainer you can use

```
$('.subContainer')[0]
```

Comment: That will still include all the nested and sub-nested subContainers.

Comment: This does not work. What if the first child of the main .subContainer is a div with .subContainer that has a child div with .container?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for my own uses...

```
$('.item').filter(function() { return $(this).parents('.item').length == 0; });
```

This returns only the `#outer` div.

```
<div class="item" id="outer">
    <div class="item" id="inner"></div>
</div>
```