# How can I find all the elements inside a container which are not inside another container using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
  <div id="nested1" class="container">
     <div class="container-element"></div>
     <div class="some-other-class">
        <div class="container-element"></div>
        <div id="nested3" class="container">
          <div class="container-element">
             <div id="nested4" class="container">
                <div class="container-element"></div>
                <div class="container-element"></div>
                <div class="container-element"></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-element"></div>
          <div class="container-element"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="nested2" class="container">
        <div class="container-element"></div>
        <div class="container-element"></div>
        <div class="container-element"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="container-element"></div>
     <div class="container-element">
        <div id="nested5" class="container">
          <div class="container-element"></div>
        </div>
     </div>  
  </div>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
     // loop body: $(this) is a '.container'
});
```

Now inside the body of the loop I need to select all the elements with class '.container-element' inside the current '.container' ***which are not inside another '.container'***, so e.g.:

- when `$(this)` points to the first outermost container with id
  `nested1`, I should select all the elements with class `.container-element`
  which are not inside another `.container` (and therefore all
  but those within `container` with id `nested2`, `nested3`, `nested4`,
  `nested5`);
- when `$(this)` points to the `.container` with id `nested3`, I should select *only* one `.container-element` and exclude the one inside `nested4`;
- when `$(this)` refers to the `.container` with id `nested5`, I should select only one `.container-element` which is its only descendant.

Of course, jQuery's `.find()` will not work. I have also tried:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
      var containerElements = $(this).find('.container-element').not('.container .container-element');
});
```

And:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
      var containerElements = $(this).find('.container-element').not('.container .container .container-element');
});
```

But they both didn't work too.

Also, please note that I cannot use `.children()` because given a `container`, I need to look for `.container-element`s which are nested too provided that they are not inside another `container`.

I have found something on SO too: [Jquery: Get all elements of a class that are not decendents of an element with the same class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624058/jquery-get-all-elements-of-a-class-that-are-not-decendents-of-an-element-with-t/12625354#12625354)

But it seems to me a bit different from what I am trying to do.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: That's confusing, but is this what you're trying to do -> **http://jsfiddle.net/h9m44y0e/**

Comment: Need to show us what should be found. Not really clear what you are needing

Comment: @adeneo Yes, the only thing is that I should assure that `.container-element` is inside a `.container` and that if I select all the `.container-element` elements inside a `.container` they should not be inside another `.container` element from that point in the DOM (from the current `.container`). The example you posted is just a case when the outermost `.container` is the current one.

Comment: Maybe `$(this).find('>.container-element')`? Note the `>` at the beginning of the selector. This would include direct children, but not farther descendants.

Comment: @VladGURDIGA It's like `$(this).children('.container-element')`, I guess, isn't it? But when `$(this)` is the `.container` with id `nested1` I should select the first child of `some-other-class` (which is a `.container-element` too)

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't understand, `$(this).children('.container-element')` selects all direct children of the current jQuery object, doesn't `$(this).find('> .container-element')` do the same?

Comment: @tonix, but it can't come across that element because it's a grandchild of `#nested3` which was ruled out, wasn't it? It seems to me, in the end, you'll get all `.container-elements` anyway - assuming you use `$(".container").each()` with further filtering inside. (Maybe the order is different from what you'd get when using `$(.container-element)` directly.) I guess what you're trying to archive is either being limited to process that jQuery-collection you get from "outside" or a matter of specific element order you want to preserve.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Yes, you are right, the order doesn't matter at the moment, but I guess that it would be trivial to do if we could, let's say, "flatten" the DOM, I mean when I am looping over the current `.container`, I somehow make jQuery believe that $(this) current `.container` is the **root element** for the next elements selection query (e.g.  for the next `.find()` and `.not()`) and then I can just do `$(this).find('container-element').not('.container .container-element')`. Is there a similar functionality in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with is the following jquery mini-plugin:

```
$.fn.findNotWithin = function(selector, nested) {
   var that = this;
   var $notWithinNestedElements = this.find(selector).filter(
       function() {
           return $(this).parent().closest(nested).not(that).length == 0;
       }
   );
    return $notWithinNestedElements;
};
```

Now, with this method:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
      var containerElements = $(this).findNotWithin('.container-element', '.container');
});
```

It works. However I am still looking for a more syntax sugared solution.

EDIT: this code is the same as the previous:

```
$.fn.findNotWithin = function(selector, nested) {
   var that = this;
   var context = this[0];
   var $notWithinNestedElements = this.find(selector).filter(
       function() {
           return $(this).parent().closest(nested, context).length == 0;
       }
   );
    return $notWithinNestedElements;
};
```

But I like it more and it uses the context parameter of `.closest()`.

Comment: Your code seems to select just all `.container-element`s: http://jsfiddle.net/anv5owk6/2/. Please fix and update my fiddle if I've used your plugin the wrong way. Otherwise it look like `$(".container-element")` would do the same job.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/anv5owk6/3/. You were applying a style to all `container-element`s which are matched throughout the whole loop, that's because you thought that the code was wrong. Check the console and see what gets matched **for each .container** instead and you will see the difference.

Comment: `$(this).findNotWithin('.container-element', '.container');` What this method does is: inside the current jQuery object (`$(this)`), match all elements of class `.container-element` provided that they are not within an element with class `.container`  beneath the current `$(this)` element, therefore, exactly what I was looking for.